# Program blocks after input

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, scanf

This code blocks immediately after `scanf()`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    puts("Algorithms test kit");
    long input_size;
    FILE *output=fopen("output.txt","w+");
    do {
        printf("Enter sample size(0 goes on to next test) > ");
        scanf (" %li ",&input_size);
        printf ("#");
        if (input_size==0) break;
        int64_t *data=sorting_prepare_data(input_size);
        int64_t *bsort_copy=calloc(input_size,8);
        int64_t *qsort_copy=calloc(input_size,8);
        memcpy(bsort_copy,data,input_size*8);
        bubblesort(bsort_copy,input_size);
        memcpy(qsort_copy,data,input_size*8);
        quicksort(qsort_copy,input_size);       
        for (size_t i=0;i<input_size;i++) {
             fprintf(output,"%lld\t%lld\t%lld\n",data[i],bsort_copy[i],qsort_copy[i]);
             printf(".");
        }
        free(data); free(bsort_copy); free(qsort_copy);
    } while (input_size);
    return;
}
```

Where `bubblesort()` and `quicksort()` are hand-written implementations of respective algorithms and `sorting_prepare_data()` is a helper function calling custom-built PRNG on an array. What is the possible cause of blocking? The program has been compiled using GCC, no errors resulted.

Comment: Try `scanf ("%li",&input_size);`

Comment: Same. However, if I replace input_size by a variable of type `size_t` and `%li` by `%z' the prompt skips over before I even have change to input.

Comment: What do you mean by blocks? Is the input readed?

Comment: If you can't debug (because you don't know how to operate gdb), at least insert a few debug printfs, e.g. for input_size.

Comment: Debug build seems to run on gdb. I stepped and even run through. I have found this blockout by debug print as you see `printf("#");` in the code.

Comment: what do you mean by block? Does it ask for input? does it crash after you enter a value?

Comment: Yes, it asks for input and I enter. And it stays there.

Comment: You didn't add a `\n` in the `printf ("#");`, so the `#` is still in the buffer and isn't printed out. I guess you have an infinite loop in one of your sorts.

Comment: You know about the `sizeof` operator, don't you? and you know that you are initializing data twice, with `calloc()`, don't you know that?

Comment: In GDB, it enters into a infinite loop of quicksort().

Comment: @456976: '\n' after "#" worked. @iharob: `int64_t` is always 64 bits.

Comment: Then the problem should be in `quicksort()`

Comment: @ErkinAlpGüney I know that, but that doesn't mean that you have to write hard to understand code just because of that, besides `sizeof(*bsort_copy)` would allow you to change the type of `bsort_copy` pointer seamlessly. In my opinion you have a really bad coding style, mixing declarations with code, and trying to put a lot of code in a single line doesn't make the code more readable but instead way less readable, you should improve your coding style, also use more white spaces to make it clear which token is which, for you because of course the compiler can read it.

Comment: 0
down vote
 

as you stated, the problem is in the quicksort() function.

Suggest either modifying this question with the source for the quicksort function or kill this question and ask a new question, focusing in the quicksort function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried you code and manage to reproduce the weird behaviour. If you remove the `" "` around `"%li"` it doesn't block anymore.

The problems were the blank spaces because `scanf` was expecting the input to match the empty space as well.

From the `scanf` documentation:

> All
>          conversions are introduced by the % (percent sign) character.  The format  string  may  also  contain other characters.  White space (such as
>    blanks, tabs, or newlines) in the format string    match  any  amount  of
>          white  space,  including    none,  in the input.  Everything else matches
>          only itself.  Scanning stops when an input  character  does  not    match
>          such  a format character.  **Scanning also stops when an input conversion
>          cannot be made**.

Source : http://www.manpages.info/linux/scanf.3.html

Comment: the leading space in the format string will NOT stop the input from being consumed.  All that leading space does in consume any leading white space.   As it happens, that is usually only needed for %s, as the other formats will 'automatically' consume leading white space.